# Is there a way to access chrome/safari url history or current url via Cordova?

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, cordova-plugins

I'm looking for a way to access current url a user visit in chrome/safari via Cordova app. Is it possible? If so, what will be the code for that?

EDIT:
Just to clarify things. The user browsing the web using chrome/safari and than launch my Cordova app. Can Cordova catch current url,the user visits in chrome/safari?

Comment: The URL the user is visiting within your app? `window.location` will do the trick. Or are you looking to spy on the separate Safari browser outside of your app?

Comment: Spying..but with user permission

Comment: In that case, no, not on iOS. Too much potential for abuse. Apple's cracked down on apps doing this sort of monitoring in the recent past: https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2019/04/the-facts-about-parental-control-apps/ You can monitor what happens within your own app's in-app browsers, but not the main Safari instance.

Comment: But what is the difference between this and a native ios/android app. Can't they access this kind of data as well?

Comment: The difference is not between Cordova and native. A native app can't access the main Safari browser's history, either. Apps are sandboxed so they cannot spy on each other like this.